# как передать массив через AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ситуация такая, добавляю записи в `БД` с перезагрузкой, решил реализовать на `AJAX`, но тут ситуация такая что тут мне нужно передать массив.

Вот что было с перезагрузкой

```
if ($_POST["save_submit_opis"]){

    function createQuer($i, $e){
        $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (id,text) VALUES";
        $limita = count($e);
        $solis = "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
                     text = VALUES(text) 
                 ";
        for($is=0; $is<$limita; $is++){
            $query .= "('{$i}','{$e[$is]}')".($is!=$limita-1?',':'');
        }
        $res = mysql_query($query.$solis);
    }
    $xId =  $_POST['id'];
    $xOpis = $_POST['text'];

    $query = createQuer($xId, $xOpis);
}
<form>
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="1"/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="123"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="2"/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="456"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="789"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="save_submit_opis" value="Сохранить изменения" />
```

А вот примерная реализация на `ajax`

```
$(document).on('click', '#save_submit_opis', function(){
    var id = $("#..").val();
    var opis = $("#..").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://xxx.xx/xx/xx.php",
            data: "id="+id+"&opis="+opis,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){ 
            }   
        }); 
});
```

Обычно раньше получал `value` простым указанием `id` элемента, но тут дело в том что у всех `class` и `id`  одинаковые и неизвестно точное количество строк. С обычно перезагрузкой все было просто нужно было указать в `name` `[]`, тогда он просто собирал все значения в массив а там уже добавлял в `БД` и тд, не столь важно. Сейчас мне интересно как все это можно реализовать на `AJAX`, передать взять все в массив передать все через `AJAX`
Может кто-то сталкивался с таким и может что-нибудь подсказать

Comment: Можете вообще плагин [ajaxSubmit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) использовать

Comment: Ты с каким Content-Type хочешь отправлять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз ты используешь *jQuery*, то можно воспользоваться **[serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**  формы. `Serialize`  возвращает строку пригодную для передачи через URL строку. Данные могут собираться с многих объектов *jQuery*, включая `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` и пр.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#save_submit_opis', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $('form');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR_URL",
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="1" />
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="123" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="2" />
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="456" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="" />
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="789" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="save_submit_opis" value="Сохранить изменения" id="save_submit_opis" />
```

На сервер придет массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 123
        )
    [opis] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 789
        )
)
```

---

Кстати замечу, что у тебя написано `on('click', '#save_submit_opis'`, хотя идентификатора у кнопки не было проставлено.. Либо поставь, либо пиши правильный селектор.

А также, раз ты вешаешь клик на кнопку с типом `submit` (что бессмысленно, раз ты отправляешь запрос ajax), то нужно предотвратить стандартное поведение при нажатии на такую кнопку за счет `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно поступить следующим образом:

HTML:

```
<form id="my-form">
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="1"/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="123"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value="2"/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="456"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="id[]" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="opis[]" type="text" value="789"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить изменения" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://xxx.xx/xx/xx.php",
        data: $('#my-form').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ 
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Указывай объект данных в таком формате, массивы предварительно создай.

```
data: {id: [], opis: []}
```

> by default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
>   https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/